# Map different URLs to same view

Tags: python, pyramid

It seems trivial enough but I can't find a valid answer to this problem.

Suppose I have two different links '/' and '/home' and I want them to point to the same view. (This means whether user opens xyz.com or xyz.com/home, same page will be displayed).

In pyramid  I tried

```
config.add_route('home','/')
config.add_route('home','home/')
```

But it raises the following exception

```
pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationConflictError: Conflicting configuration actions
  For: ('route', 'home')
```

How should I actually implement this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add them under different route names (they must be unique per application):

```
config.add_route('home','/')
config.add_route('home1','home/')
```

and then configure the same view for both:

```
config.add_view(yourview, route_name='home')
config.add_view(yourview, route_name='home1')
```

or, in case of using `@view_config` decorator, double-decorate your method:

```
@view_config(route_name='home')
@view_config(route_name='home1') 
def your_method(request):
   .....
```